# How to check which jenkins job is responsible for an artifact upload in artifactory

Tags: jenkins, artifactory, artifact

We have a lot of jenkins jobs (400+). A lot of them are uploading new artifacts to our Artifactory. Most of them are using the Artifactory plugin.
When we use that plugin we can check the 'build browser' in Artifactory.

This will show the jenkins jobs which are uploading artifacts with that plugin. It's clear.

The problem is that we also have some jobs in which case it isn't useful for us to implement the artifactory plugin. Is there a way in Artifactory we can check those jobs?

We want to see from an artifact which is uploaded WITHOUT the artifactory plugin from which jenkins job it's coming from.

Comment: Are you uploading artifacts using JFrog CLI, Artifactory REST API...?

Comment: Most of the time we use maven release (without the plugin)

Comment: You can use JFrog CLI and have it track the "build info"

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins jobs that use the `jfrog cli` to upload artifacts can now also publish build info.

From the jfrog cli help

```
JFROG_CLI_BUILD_NAME
    Build name to be used by commands which expect a build name, unless sent as a command argument or option.

  JFROG_CLI_BUILD_NUMBER
    Build number to be used by commands which expect a build number, unless sent as a command argument or option.

  JFROG_CLI_BUILD_PROJECT
    Artifactory project key.

  JFROG_CLI_BUILD_URL
    Sets the CI server build URL in the build-info. The "jfrog rt build-publish" command uses the value of this environment variable, unless the --build-url command option is sent.
```

Setting these environment vars during the Jenkins job and then calling
`jfrog rt build-publish` will allow you to connect the jobs to the artifacts.